# Want to make a cache

Tags: vb.net, caching, memoization

Here's the code for the problem I'm having. It's pretty simple but I'm still learning.
I want to cache the result so the function returns a few seconds quicker than it currently is. At the moment it is returning to the caller in 4 when it should be 2.

```
Sub Main
    console.writeline(getmyresult(2)) 'takes a while'
    console.writeline(getmyresult(3)) 'takes a while'
    console.writeline(getmyresult(2)) 'Should be instant'
    console.writeline(getMyresult(3)) 'Should be instant'
End Sub


function getMyresult(X as interger) as integer
    dim Y as integer=LongCompute(X)
    return Y
end function


function LongCompute(X as integer) as integer
    system.threading.thread.sleep(1000)
    return x^2
end function
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You've shown us what you are trying to do but not what the problem is.

Comment: @Chris i have been struggling trying to do anything i was told to create it with a dictionary but i could not make head nor tail of how to do it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, this is called memo-ization.

You can read up on it here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization

A simple implementation in visual basic would look like:

```
Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer)

Sub Main()
    console.writeline(getmyresult(2)) 'takes a while'
    console.writeline(getmyresult(3)) 'takes a while'
    console.writeline(getmyresult(2)) 'Should be instant'
    console.writeline(getMyresult(3)) 'Should be instant'
End Sub

Function getMyresult(ByVal X As Integer) As Integer
    If dict.ContainsKey(X) Then
        Return dict(X)
    Else
        Dim temp = LongCompute(X)
        dict.Add(X, temp)
        Return temp
    End If
End Function

Function LongCompute(ByVal X As Integer) As Integer
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    Return x ^ 2
End Function
```

Comment: Didn't know it had a specific name - learn something useful every day ;-)

Comment: @Paul_R Thank you i will read up on this thank you for the answer but it will be useless if i do not understand once again thank you

Answer (score 2):

For a simple exercise you can put the results into a Dictionary, as James Culshaw suggested. The key is the input, the value is the cached result.

If this was for serious work I would rather consider using `System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache`. The problem with a dictionary is that items never get out of it (in a way they leak, altough if the input domain is bounded it's not that bad). A production-ready cache would handle memory pressure or support items expiration (e.g. cache the result for 10 minutes). Those requirements are handled by `MemoryCache`.

Caching the result of a function that has no side-effect and depends only on its inputs is formally called Memoization. A nice extension to your programming exercise would be to write a generic memoization function that can wrap any regular (slow) function. E.g. `FastCompute = Memoize(SlowCompute)`.

Comment: @jods thanks man i will use this also in a seperate part of my coursework as it will show the basic answer and the professional answer thank you kind sir. !!!

Answer (score 1):

Simple option would be to use a Dictionary object and then check to see if the key has been set for the parameter passed into getmyresult. If it has, pass the value stored in the dictionary, if not process the result, add it to the dictionary, and then return the result. second call will be near instantaneous as its already cached in the dictionary.